# I accidentally changed the program associated with the .snk extension

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, registry, snk

Which program should be associated with the .snk extension.

I accidentally changed the association and don't know what it was prior to my change.

I want to set it back.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by Neil, there is no program associated with .snk files. What you can try doing is cleaning up the registry.

Open Regedit, navigate to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT node`, expand it and scroll down till you find the `.snk` suffix. Make sure it has no data under that key, except for the `(Default)` value which should be `VSTA.snk.9.0`, which is a redirection to the application keys further down the same branch in the treeview.

I've also got other versions of VS installed as well as VS2010, i'm not sure what its value should be if you only have VS2010, i would look to see if you have a `VSTA.snk.10.0` key.

Comment: The icon displayed before I messed up was a sort of certificate.  The registry has "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\msenvico.dll",-217 which is the icon I could see for my .snk file before I altered the associated program. I don't see how to remove the associated program.

Comment: My Registry looks OK as far as I can tell.  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.snk/Default = 'VCExpress.snk.10.0'  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/VCExpress.snk.10.0/Default = 'Visual Studio Strong Name Key File'  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/VCExpress.snk.10.0/NoOpen exists with no value  
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/VCExpress.snk.10.0/DefaultIcon/Default =
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\msenvico.dll",-217  
I also have VSTA.snk.9.0 which is set up just the same.

Comment: Oops, it's VSTA/snk.8.0 on mine not 9.0

Answer (score 0):

From Explorer, open Tools, Folder Options. Scroll down the list of file types until you find the .snk extension. Then click Restore.

Note that there is no default program associated with the extension on my system, but it says it's of type Visual Studio Strong Name Key File.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Windows 7.  File associations are now in Control Panel and there is no restore function.

Comment: The registry has "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\msenvico.dll",-217 which is the icon I could see for my .snk file before I altered the associated program.  I don't see how to reset this for .snk files.

Comment: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.snk` should only have a default value of `<APP>.snk.<VERSION>`. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<APP>.snk.<VERSION>` should have a default value of "Visual Studio Strong Name Key File", an EditFlags of 0x00000000, a NoOpen of "" and a DefaultIcon key with the value as you already know.

Comment: Also check out HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes in case you have a personal override of the association.

Comment: I've added HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/VCExpress.snk.10.0/EditFlags as REG_DWORD 0x00000000 but it's had no effect.  Do I need to reload?  There is no HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.snk entry.